# Teechart Barchart Coloring issue

Tags: activex, teechart

I am using Teechart Active X control. I have created a Bar chart and provided added some values, I also Added a tee commander and made it link with my chart. Now when I change the Series color in the Editing the same is not reflected in my Chart. But if I do fillSample value it works fine.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are populating your series using an Add function that takes a `Color` argument.

Note that, if you assign a `Color` to the series points, this `Color` assigned to the points prevals to the series' `Color` property. That's why changing the series `Color` doesn't have any visual effect.

Calling `FillSampleValues` function, the list of colors is cleared; that's why the series `Color` seems to work then.

If you already added the points assigning a `Color` to each one, you could clear the list of colors looping into the array, assigning `clTeeColor` to all them:

```
  For i = 0 To TChart1.Series(0).Count - 1
    TChart1.Series(0).PointColor(i) = clTeeColor
  Next i
```

If you can't use the clTeeColor constant, use its value directly:

```
clTeeColor = 536870912
```

Comment: Yeah I am using Add Function with Color.I tried setting ColorEachPoint after Add fuction but still the color change are not reflected. MY requirement is initially the Bar should be colored with Color Specify and then the user can change the color.